# String with decimal point to double VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would need help with this code. I have a string with number with decimal point like "-12.9" and need it convert to double.

Here is the code:

```
Dim Z_pos as double
Dim word as string = "-12.9"
Z_pos = Convert.ToDouble(word)
```

But I  got error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input format is incorrect.'

UPDATE

Solved with the following code:

```
Dim Z_pos as double
Dim word as string = "-12.9"
word.Replace(".", ",")
Z_pos = Convert.ToDouble(word)
```

But seems that isn't an optimal solution either.

Comment: And which error do you get?

Comment: In the Czech Republic it needs to be "-12,9" to not generate an FormatException.  You can add a CultureInfo.InvariantCulture argument to make a decimal point acceptable.

Comment: You should provide an example of the error you are getting. Take a look at the guidelines on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Solved -

```
Dim Z_pos as double
Dim word as string = "-12.9"
word.Replace(".", ",")
Z_pos = Convert.ToDouble(word)
```

Do you have some better solution?

Comment: Yes, `Convert.ToDouble("-12.9", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use val like this

```
Dim Z_pos as double
Dim word as string = "-12.9"
Z_pos = val(word)
```